# Bitlocker like capability for Linux?

Tags: linux, disk-encryption

As you know large company IT departments generally enable Bitlocker on any Windows laptop. Generally, one does not notice an issue with this and it is relatively effective in protecting the raw disk from data being disclosed.

Is there anything like this type of easy to enable/invisible encryption on Linux?

Comment: `cryptsetup`?  Available pretty much on any distro today.

Comment: The installer makes it easy to do out of the box, [doing so after the install...not so much](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1710330) but yeah, if you start out with encrypted root, it's incredibly simple and robust.

Comment: @Bratchley Home directory encryption with ecryptfs is easy at any time. It's only whole disk encryption that requires partition juggling.

Answer (score 1):

`dm-crypt` is widely used for encrypting block devices on Linux.
It can be set up to ask for a passphrase on boot, or by requiring a USB key to be inserted when the system is turned on (there's a good write up on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713918/how-to-load-luks-passphrase-from-usb-falling-back-to-keyboard)).

There is also `ecryptfs` which can create encrypted directories that can be decrypted automatically upon logging in to the system.

Comment: But this is unlike bitlocker, where you don't enter a key (unless the partition cannot be mounted).  Thus, the protection is basically to prevent the encrypted disk from being used in an outside system